# Help on understanding how _id works for Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, node.js

So I've got a schema for a record  that is shown below that will record three different types of events:
(an example of one record that would be created that would be a segment in the test log) (log just holds an array of objects)

```
{
                        date_started: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
                        date_ended: null,
                        _id: //idk,
                        type: 'test',
                        log: [],
}
```

When one is created it receives its specific type (of which there are 3). How would I set up unique serial ids for each type? Would I need to use individual schemas?
Trying to explain in a different way:
I've got three logs to keep that all take identical inputs. How would I keep the serial number separate if I used _id? I'm rather new to MongoDB and any direction you can point me in would help. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to DBA StackExchange! Can you clarify your use case: does "serial IDs" refer to a serial number for a device that would be captured in each event or are you thinking of creating sequential `_id` values? The `_id` value has to be unique, so if you want to create events with the same serial value but different types, your data model would need a separate field like `serial`.